Photo library permission is denied
I am trying to access the photo library with image_picker for my app , for the user to add cover photo but I can't find any request when I access the Settings>Privacy>Photos and also the app when I scroll the settings down it's not appearing
here is the code
class WorkoutContentAdded extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkoutContentAddedState createState() => _WorkoutContentAddedState();
}

class _WorkoutContentAddedState extends State<WorkoutContentAdded> {
  String? coverPhotoUrl;
  File? _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('No programs available'));
          }

          DocumentSnapshot firstDocument = snapshot.data!.docs.first;
          Map<String, dynamic> firstData = firstDocument.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 300,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      coverPhotoUrl != null
                          ? Image.file(
                              File(coverPhotoUrl!),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                          : Image.asset(
                              'assets/cover_photo.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 16,
                        right: 16,
                        bottom: 16,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              firstData['title'] ?? 'No title',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 8),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    firstData['category'] ?? 'N/A',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 8),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    (firstData['days'] as List<dynamic>?)?.map((day) => day.toString()[0].toUpperCase()).join(' ') ?? 'N/A',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: _showBottomSheet,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Add cover photo button pressed");
                    _pickImage();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Add cover photo',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 12),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                Text(
                  'Add more details about the workout',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Do you use any equipment for the workouts?',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'eg: 2kg dumbbells, 3kg ball',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // TODO: Implement save functionality
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    print("_pickImage method started");
    try {
      // Check current permission status
      var status = await Permission.photos.status;
      print("Current photo library permission status: $status");

      if (status.isGranted) {
        await _proceedWithImagePicking();
      } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        print("Photo library permission is permanently denied");
        // Show a dialog explaining why the permission is needed and how to enable it
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Permission Required'),
            content: Text('Photo library access is required to select a cover photo. Please enable it in your device settings.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Open Settings'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  await openAppSettings();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // Permission is denied but not permanently. We can request it.
        status = await Permission.photos.request();
        if (status.isGranted) {
          await _proceedWithImagePicking();
        } else {
          print("Photo library permission is denied");
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Permission not granted. Please try again.')),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error in _pickImage: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error selecting image: $e')),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _proceedWithImagePicking() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    print("Attempting to pick an image");
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image != null) {
      print("Image picked: ${image.path}");
      setState(() {
        _image = File(image.path);
        coverPhotoUrl = image.path;
      });
      print("Cover photo URL set to: $coverPhotoUrl");

      // Show a success message
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Cover photo updated successfully')),
      );
    } else {
      print('No image selected');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _uploadImage() async {
    // Implement image upload functionality here
  }
}

and here is the info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Influfit</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>influfit</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Access to your camera is required to capture photos required for loan processing or your profile.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To show your location on the map.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Access to your photo library is required to select photos for your profile or loan processing.</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong? I leave here a video of the issue https://imgur.com/a/qkL8HKZ

what package did you use for handling permission?
